# Race condition caused by mvar

Tags: scala, concurrency, scala-cats, cats-effect

Consider the following simple example:

```
implicit val timer: Timer[IO]     = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)
implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

val mvarF = MVar.of[IO, mutable.Map[Int, Int]](mutable.Map.empty)

mvarF.flatMap(mvar =>

  mvar.take.bracket(st => {
    IO(st.put(1, 1)) >> (IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(st.clear())).start
  })(mvar.put)
    >>
  mvar.take.bracket(st =>
    IO(println(s"Size before sleep ${st.size}")) >> IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(println(s"Size after sleep ${st.size}"))
  )(mvar.put)

).unsafeRunSync()
```

It prints:

```
Size before sleep 1
Size after sleep 0
```

In this example the job scheduled under fiber modifies the object under mvar which is acquired by another job.

This extremely unsafe. Is there a way to prohibit such usage?

Comment: Yeah, don't use a mutable variable. If you share a mutable variable you are just unsafe.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It's not always practical especially in case of large collections.

Comment: How sure you are that using an immutable map inside the `MVar` would not be practical?  And if you re then you can't do anything, you want something to be mutable and immutable at the same time, is simply not possible.

Comment: Also, the `release` action of `bracket` will run almost immediately because your `use` function starts a fiber. And if you want to control access to a mutable thing you should probably use something else than `MVar` which controls mutation of itself, not of the object it points to.

Comment: I think the main confusion here is that you say "the mvar is acquired by another job", but it is not. You take the value out of the mvar and then you mutate that value (not the mvar itself). At that point the mvar is not acquired by anyone anymore.

Comment: this question is just weird. You are mutating the value reffered to by the variable. `MVar` provides you control over re-assignment of the variable. `MVar` can not magically upgrade a non-thread-safe thing into being thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed by Jasper, your main problem (for this specific code example) is that you are releasing the `bracket` after starting a new fiber in your `use` by calling `IO(st.put(1, 1)) >> (IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(st.clear())).start`. So your use is actually an `mutable.Map[Int, Int] => IO[Fiber[IO, Unit]]`.

You just have to remove that `start` and you will have intended behaviour (your use will be `mutable.Map[Int, Int] => IO[Unit]` and `bracket` will not be released unless your `use` `IO` completes.). This means that the map will alreay be empty for both print actions.

```scala
mvarF.flatMap(mvar =>
  mvar.take.bracket(st => {
    IO(st.put(1, 1)) >>
      IO.sleep(2.seconds) >>
        IO(st.clear())
  })(mvar.put)
    >>
    mvar.take.bracket(st =>
      IO(println(s"Size before sleep ${st.size}")) >>
        IO.sleep(2.seconds) >>
          IO(println(s"Size after sleep ${st.size}"))
    )(mvar.put)

).unsafeRunSync()
```

```
Size before sleep 0
Size after sleep 0
```

But this is actually just a conincidence for this specific code example (IO's are being chained with flatMap which means we are telling the runtime to sequentially perform these IO's).

`MVar` provides you control over re-assignment of the variable, but your are not doing any re-assignment at all. Hence, this code is not even using any capbilities of `MVar`, its just sitting there as an spectator.

So, the usage of `MVar` in this way will have ZERO impact on thread saftey of your code.

```
mvarF.flatMap(mvar =>
  mvar.take.bracket(st =>
    IO(println(s"Size before first sleep - ${st.size}")) >> IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(println(s"Size after first sleep - ${st.size}"))
  )(mvar.put)
).unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()

mvarF.flatMap(mvar =>
  mvar.take.bracket(st => {
    IO(st.put(1, 1)) >> IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(st.clear())
  })(mvar.put)
).unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()

mvarF.flatMap(mvar =>
    mvar.take.bracket(st =>
      IO(println(s"Size before second sleep - ${st.size}")) >> IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(println(s"Size after second sleep - ${st.size}"))
    )(mvar.put)
).unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()
```

```
Size before first sleep - 0
Size before second sleep - 1
Size after first sleep - 0
Size after second sleep - 0
```

You can use Semaphore to get a race free scope.

```scala
class IOWithSemaphore[A](
    private val a: A, 
    private val semaphore: Semaphore[IO]
  )(
    implicit
    F: Concurrent[IO],
    T: Timer[IO]) {

  def unitUse(use: A => IO[Unit]): IO[Unit] =
    for {
      _ <- semaphore.acquire
      _ <- use(a)
      _ <- semaphore.release
    } yield ()

}
```

```scala
val map = mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]

Semaphore[IO](1).map(semaphore => {
  val mapIOWithSemaphore = new IOWithSemaphore[mutable.Map[Int, Int]](map, semaphore)

  // using unsafeRunAsync to emulate the parallel usage

  mapIOWithSemaphore.unitUse(map =>
    IO(println(s"Size before first sleep - ${map.size}")) >> IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(println(s"Size after first sleep - ${map.size}"))
  ).unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()

  mapIOWithSemaphore.unitUse(map =>
    IO(println(s"MUTATION BEGIN")) >> IO(map.put(1, 1)) >> IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(map.clear()) >> IO(println(s"MUTATION END"))
  ).unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()

  mapIOWithSemaphore.unitUse(map =>
    IO(println(s"Size before second sleep - ${map.size}")) >> IO.sleep(2.seconds) >> IO(println(s"Size after second sleep - ${map.size}"))
  ).unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()

}).unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()

Await.result(Promise[Unit].future, Duration.Inf)
```

```
Size before first sleep - 0
Size after first sleep - 0
MUTATION BEGIN
MUTATION END
Size before second sleep - 0
Size after second sleep - 0
```